# How to write custom attributes (ATTRS{attribute_name} to a USB-Device?

Tags: bash, usb, hardware

I have 2 identical devices which I want to differentiate using udev rules.

However, after executing the following for the devices, I have found out that the Serial Number is missing from the given hardware for 1 device.

For every device this serial number should be unique and visible.

When the good one only is connected it shows the Serial Number,

```
$ udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0) | grep -i Serial
ATTRS{serial}=="XXXXXXXX"
```

When the faulty one only is connected it does not show serial number.

```
$ udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB1) | grep -i Serial

$
```

When the good one only is connected:

```
$ ls /dev/serial/by-id/*
/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_DEVICE-NAME_XXXXXXXX-if00-port0
```

When the faulty one only is connected:

```
$ ls /dev/serial/by-id/*
/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_DEVICE-NAME_-if00-port0
```

So is there a way to add a custom attribute to these devices, so I can differentiate them using udev rules?

Something like a command or a program to do

```
$ attribute_writing_binary /dev/tty_device_path "ATTRS{custom_attribute}=value"
```

---

Note: Resources and solutions I have looked at so far are based on rules which port the devices are connected to. My intention is that the key-value pair of strings written to the device be persistent on the device itself and retains the values when connected to another machine, so I can deploy on multiple hardware instances, and I can assign identification.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your devices are presented as `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_DEVICE-NAME_*` devices suggests that FTDI USB-to-serial converter chips (or their counterfeit clones) are used in your devices.

As far as I know, the genuine FTDI USB-to-serial converter chips don't support assigning custom attributes; however, they do support the optional assignment of a custom vendor/product identifier and/or a serial number. This functionality is intended to be used while manufacturing the device to which the chip is going to be integrated, and those parameters might only be settable *once*, and permanent after that.

The tool for configuring FTDI chips is called `FT_PROG`, and it is [available here](https://ftdichip.com/utilities/#ft_prog), although for Windows only.
[Here is the user guide for it.](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/AN_124_User_Guide_For_FT_PROG.pdf)

Be aware that counterfeit (fake) USB-to-serial chips seem to have been a big problem for FTDI in recent years, so much that they seem to have once [released a version of their drivers that will actively attempt to detect the fake products and cause them to fail permanently](https://hackaday.com/2016/02/01/ftdi-drivers-break-fake-chips-again/).

The `FT_PROG` tool is intended for use while manufacturing the devices that incorporate such chips, so in the eyes of the chip manufacturer, it would be in an even better spot to disable any counterfeit chips it finds: if a counterfeit chip is disabled during the device manufacturing process, it would only hurt the manufacturer that is using counterfeit chips instead of genuine ones, and not harm the end users of the devices.

So, if you attempt to use FT_PROG to configure unique serial numbers for your devices, and one of those devices includes a fake chip, **there is a risk that this program might disable the chip in your device.**

Some (older) versions of the FTDI USB-to-serial chips also seem to require a small external EEPROM chip to support the programmable identifiers, and if your "faulty" device has its EEPROM failed or missing, there will be nothing you can do it at the software level.